# Не работает ссылка из-за 'clear: right'

Tags: html, css

Не работает ссылка, выяснил что это из-за свойства 'clear', как сделать так чтоб тэги h2 и a располагались друг под другом и при этом работала ссылка? Пробовал заменить тэг а на button и input, результат тот же

```css
.text__content {
    text-align: right;
}

.text__heading {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 120%;
    font-family: oswald-vh, sans-serif;
    max-width: 60%;
    float: right;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    display: block;
}

.button {
    background-color: green;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 10px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border: none;
    position: relative;
    padding: 14px 25px;
    font-weight: 800;
    float: right;
    clear: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="text__content">
  <h2 class="text__heading">1967 Ford Mustang <span class="shelby">Shelby GT500</span> Eleanor</h2>
  <button onclick="window.open('https://www.ford.com/cars/mustang/models/shelby-gt500/')" class="button">Узнать больше</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Пример

```css
.text__content {
    text-align: right;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;    
    align-items: flex-end;
    font-family: oswald-vh, sans-serif;
}

.text__heading {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 120%;    
    max-width: 60%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    display: block;
}

.button {
    background-color: green;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 10px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border: none;
    position: relative;
    padding: 14px 25px;
    font-weight: 800;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="text__content">
  <h2 class="text__heading">1967 Ford Mustang <span class="shelby">Shelby GT500</span> Eleanor</h2>
  <a href="https://www.ford.com/cars/mustang/models/shelby-gt500/" class="button">Узнать больше</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, я разобрался, у меня просто под text-content находился полупрозрачный блок с z-index, Он и перекрывал ссылку)